# To check modification of file

Tags: java

We have multiple file in a module that lets say we wanna check which file got modified.

What I have found out is that it can be achieved using md5 algorithm.So request you guys to lets me know how we can do this.I am not asking for code but away how to do it.

Comment: if you want to check for modifications you need to have some information about previous state. Previous md5 checksum for example

Comment: can you example in more details

Comment: md5 is a checksum of a file, each time you change your file the checksum changes with it. You can compare those checksums to check if file was modified.

Comment: Can we do it for a folder ?

Comment: Lets say a folder has 1000s of files so can you get the list of files which got modified in that folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DigestUtils from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) to check for modification.

```
Map<File, ByteArray> filelist = new HashMap<File, ByteArray>();
// add files here

for(Map.Entry<File, ByteArray> e: filelist) {
    FileInputStream fi = FileUtils.openInputStream(e.getKey());
    byte[] digest = DigestUtils.sha1(fi);
    // save digest to a new map, list, etc. or just compare it to any previous state.
    e.getValue().equals(new ByteArray(digest));
}
```

Where ByteArray is a wrapper for byte[].

Answer (score 0):

you can Check Last Modification of file Using Java Code

```
public class CheclLastModificationTimeOfFile {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    File fileToTest = new File("/home/ananddw/Anand.json");
    if (!fileToTest.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("File donated with given path is a File");
        Date dt = new Date(fileToTest.lastModified());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss ");
        System.out.println("Last Modification time is :"
                + sdf.format(dt).toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("File donated with given path is a Directory");
        Date dt = new Date(fileToTest.lastModified());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss ");
        System.out.println("Last Modification time is :"
                + sdf.format(dt).toString());
   }
   }
   }
```

it works like what you want Deploy and Check